# How to call jQuery fileupload to Html block added dynamically by Ajax?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use jQuery Ajax file upload plugin and everything is fine until there is a need to call a method that apply plugin to file inputs that were added to the page by Ajax.

```
 $('.ajax-upload').fileupload({
     dataType: 'json',
     done: function (e, data) {
          alert('yo');                   
     }
 });
```

The above works fine, but not the HTML content added dynamically by Ajax.

I tried .live and .on but didn't find any handler to put the fileupload() method call to.

How make fileupload() method be called on all .ajax-upload elements, even those that are added by Ajax later?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign those event listeners after the elements have entered the DOM.  Try defining your event listeners in the success event that follows a successful html import via jQ.